# Removing spaces and anything that is not alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, alphanumeric

I'm trying to remove everything that is not alphanumeric, or is a space with _:

```
$filename = preg_replace("([^a-zA-Z0-9]|^\s)", "_", $filename);
```

What am I doing wrong here, it doesn't seem to work. I've tried several regex combinations...(and I'm generally not very bright).

Comment: I'm slightly confused--do you want to replace spaces with "_" or no?

Comment: Well, for one thing you’ve managed to neglect quite a few characters: `ˋunichars -a '[\p{Alpha}\p{Number}]' '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' | wc -lˋ == 14717`. Not a good place to start.

Comment: You should put the `\s` in the square brackets. Otherwise `^\s` matches just whitespaces at the start `^` of the subject. Also use `/../` for enclosing, round brackets are only for capturing.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace spaces and everything that isn't alphanumeric with an underscore _

Comment: `[^\pL\pN]` is any single nonalphanumeric character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "_", $filename);
```

Comment: I suggest accounting for the other almost 15000 characters you forgot about.

Answer (score 7):

```
$filename = preg_replace('~[\W\s]~', '_', $filename);
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace any space (\s) or non-alphanumerical (\W) character with a '_'. This should do fine. Note the \W is uppercase, as opposed to lowercase \w which would match alphanumerical characters.

Comment: The meaning of `\W` varies from one flavor to the next, but in PHP it matches any character that's not an ASCII word character, i.e.  `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  That includes ASCII whitespace characters (so the `\s` is redundant) and alphanumeric characters from other scripts.  Even accented Latin letters are considered non-word characters by `\W`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that works for me is:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $filename);
```

The `+` matches blocks of one or more occurances of `\W` whitespace which includes spaces and all non-alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$filename = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]|\s/", "_", $filename);
```

Comment: Wow. Um, like what is that `\s` doing *outside* the character class?   And what about the thousands of alphanumerics you forgot about, eh?