# Keep only a-z and underscore characters

Tags: php, string

How do I strip all characters from a string, besides `a-z` (with uppercase) and the underscore `_` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing spaces and anything that is not alphanumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210419/removing-spaces-and-anything-that-is-not-alphanumeric)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about a regular expression?

```
$output = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z_]#', '', $input);
```

This replaces everything that matches the expression with an empty string.

[] is a group of symbols, the ^ at the beginning of the group means: this group contains every character that is NOT mentioned afterwards. So it contains everything that is not a-z or A-Z or the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about [regular expressions](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php). Try this

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z_]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `preg_replace` function for this:

```
$string = 'Text& with* ch@racters that get# removed, but_not_underscore.';
echo preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z_]/', '', $string );
```