# Regex: Replace any non-alphanumeric string except space

Tags: php, regex

My Apologies, I have never gotten to grips with regex expressions.

I need to remove anything (from a product name, some of them have ampersands in them) that isnt alphanumeric from a string, excluding the spaces.

So far I have this (found from another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210419/removing-spaces-and-anything-that-is-not-alphanumeric)):

```
$productname = preg_replace("~[\W]~","",$product['name']);
```

Now this replaces everything that is alphanumeric with "".  Which is fine, except I want to exclude spaces as It is currently removing all spaces.  Also, i cannot find anywhere what the tilde (`~`) does in regex.

With regards to the spaces, I have seen that there is a *negative lookahead*, achieved by `?!`, but how to incorporate that in the above I don't know.

Comment: the ~ is a delimiter for PCRE regex, http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: `I have never gotten to grips with regex expressions.` Regex means "regular expressions", so you don't need to say regex expressions, because it's like saying: regular expressions expressions. Just a hint. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, i cannot find anywhere what the tilde (~) does in regex.

Regular expressions in PHP are enclosed in set of delimiters, usually `~` but you can use any non-alphanumeric character except for a few which are mentioned in the documentation.

Now if you want to replace any non-alphanumeric excluding spaces then you can do:

```
~[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+~
```

- `^` inside the character class `[]` makes the character class match anything not mentioned inside of it like `[^a]` matches anything but `a`.
- `a-z` match small letters.
- `A-Z` match uppercase letters.
- `0-9` match digits.
- `\s` match space characters.
- `^` makes the previous class match everything but what was mentioned.
- `+` after the characters class, makes the character class match one or more characters which are not mentioned in the character class.

`\W` alone matches non-word characters, so what are word characters ?

Word characters are usually any letters *(small, uppercase)*, digits or underscore `_`.

Word characters `\w` *(with small `w`)* are usually equal to this character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_`].

`\W` *(big `W`)* matches non-word characters so it matches anything but what `\w` matches including spaces, so it will remove the spaces also.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, it wipes my whole string clean.  I want to remove **all** alaphanumeric characters *except* spaces?

Comment: @Chud37 You want to remove all alphanumeric or **non** alphanumeric ?

Comment: Sorry: I want to remove **all** non-alaphanumeric characters **except** spaces

Comment: @Chud37 You are correct, sorry for this. I am gonna fix it or remove the answer.

Comment: I didn't try it, I don't understand the logic in replacing \W with the extended version?

Comment: Brilliant, well explained, and works perfectly.  Thank you so much @Sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple negation in class block

```
$productname = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z0-9]+#","",$product['name']);
```

it will replace with "" everything what is not alphanumeric

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the above please? Also, why did you lose the `\W` in favor for `A-Za-z0-9`, and why is your start `^` inside the `[]`?

Comment: `^` is used for negation it means that the characters inside class cannot be in word.

Comment: This also removes the spaces.